# If I build an Alchemy Machine, do I need to keep my Science Machine?

Tags: dont-starve

I managed to get my hands on an Alchemy Machine in *Don't Starve*. This machine gives me access to the Tier 2 crafting prototypes compared to the Science Machine's Tier 1 prototypes.

However, I'm not sure if I can destroy my Science Machine now that I have my Alchemy Machine. Will I lose access to the Science Machine recipes?

**What happens if I destroy my Science Machine with an Alchemy Machine in place?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The wiki appears to say that an Alchemy Machine can be used to prototype everything that the Science Machine can:

> The Science Machine is used to unlock tier 1 items, and the Alchemy
>   Engine is used to unlock tier 1 and tier 2 items, making the Alchemy
>   Engine the higher level Prototyping machine.

I believe I've seen this for myself, standing by my Alchemy Machine and prototyping Tier 1 technology. Therefore, you should be able to destroy your Science Machine with no negative effects.

Comment: Yes, [can confirm](https://imgur.com/a/JV2CuHW).